# Extracting HTML nodes using Jsoup

Tags: html-parsing, web-crawler, jsoup, extract, html-content-extraction

This is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Instructor's Page</title>

<body>

<h1>Instructor's Page</h1>


<div class="check1">    <div id="check2">
<span id="check3" class="check4"> <strong class="check5"><link href="http://schema.org/t"/>Instructor-1 name</strong>
</span>
</div>

<div class="check1">    <div id="check2">
<span id="check3" class="check4"> <strong class="check6">Instructor-2 name</strong>
</span>

</body>
</html>
```

I am very new to `Jsoup`. How to extract `Instructor's name` from the given html page?

Currently, I know only printing the title.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;


public class crawl {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Document doc1;

        try {


            File input = new File("t.html");
            doc1 = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8");
        // get page title

            String title1 = doc1.title();
            System.out.println("title : " + title1);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `select`-method to select those elements in the HTML page you want.
It takes a pattern as an argument to what objects you want to select, such as a specific tag with a certain id or class.

```
//Creates a collection of Element objects for all span tags
Elements names = doc.select("span");

//Returns a collection of the first cells of each row
Elements names = doc.select("td:eq(0)");
```

Use this to select what you are looking for. Using a tool in your web browser that helps you identify tags in the HTML source can be helpful.

As to your original question on how to select instructor names, see below.

---

If the structure of the HTML always is the same and you are certain that the instructors name will be inside a `span`-tag, then you can simply parse the text in the

```
    Elements names = doc.select("span");
    for (Element e : names) {
        System.out.println("Name is: " + e.text());
    }
```

Will print out

```
Name is: Instructor-1 name
Name is: Instructor-2 name
```